# Loading JSON data into apache age viewer?

Tags: apache-age

I want to load the following data to AGE. How can I do that?

**Data:**

```
{
  "vertices": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "label": "Person",
      "properties": {
        "name": "John",
        "age": 25
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "label": "Person",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Alice",
        "age": 30
      }
    }
  ],
  "edges": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "label": "FRIENDS_WITH",
      "source": 1,
      "target": 2,
      "properties": {
        "since": "2022-01-01"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the above procedure by following below steps:

1. Create a graph in age viewer
2. Create labels
3. create indexes on the created labels
4. After the indexes just load data using copy command to import the data.
5. after successful loading you can query and visualize the data using age-viewer

A sample Code:

```
Create graph newgraph;
Create label personLabel;
Create label friends_withLabel;

Create graph index ON personLabel;
Create graph index ON friends_withLabel;

Copy personLabel(id, name, age) from 'Path to your json file';
Copy friends_withLabel(id, source, target, since) from 'Path to your json file';
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache AGE makes use of the openCypher query language. I would suggest transforming your JSON data into an equivalent set of Cypher CREATE queries.

```
CREATE (n:Person {id: 1, name: 'John', age: 25});
CREATE (m:Person {id: 2, name: 'Alice', age: 30});
CREATE (n)-[:FRIENDS_WITH {id: 1, since: '2022-01-01'}]->(m);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of **Cypher Queries** to load your data into an Apache AGE graph.

```
-- Create the graph
CREATE GRAPH mygraph;

-- Load the vertices
CALL apoc.load.json('file:///path/to/your/data.json') YIELD value
UNWIND value.vertices AS vertex
MERGE (n:Person {id: vertex.id})
SET n.name = vertex.properties.name,
    n.age = vertex.properties.age;

-- Load the edges
CALL apoc.load.json('file:///path/to/your/data.json') YIELD value
UNWIND value.edges AS edge
MATCH (source:Person {id: edge.source})
MATCH (target:Person {id: edge.target})
CREATE (source)-[r:FRIENDS_WITH {since: edge.properties.since}]->(target);
```

Make sure to replace `'file:///path/to/your/data.json'` with the actual path to your JSON data file.

In these queries, the `apoc.load.json` procedure is used to load the JSON data. The `UNWIND` clause is used to iterate over the vertices and edges arrays in the JSON data. The `MERGE` statement is used to create or match the vertices, and the `SET` clause assigns the properties to the vertices. For edges, the `MATCH` clause is used to find the source and target vertices, and the `CREATE` statement is used to create the relationships.

You can use the `age-viewer` tool to view the data in the graph. To do this, you will need to open the age-viewer tool and select the Add Graph option. In the Add Graph dialog box, specify the name of the graph (mygraph) and the location of the graph database (~/.age/mygraph). Click on the Open button.

The age-viewer tool will display the graph in a graphical format. You can use the Query tab to enter Cypher queries to explore the data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function available in Apache Age that can directly transform your data into a graph database. You have to write a script which will convert your whole data in the form of cypher queries which can then be executed to get the graph database.

The script should do the following things

- First, make the vertex.
- Then it should add the nodes to that vertex along with their properties.
- Then it should see the edges data and make the edges between the nodes.
- Lastly, it should return all the cypher queries which can then be executed to get this data in the Apache Age.

For the above example, it should generate three cypher queries:

- First one for creating John named Person
- The second one for creating Alice named Person
- Third one for making the relationship between them.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps can be followed to load the relevant data into Apache AGE:

1. Make sure that the graph schema is designed according to the data labels that you'll need.
2. Use the "GRAPH_IO" module to export the data into Apache AGE.
3. Now you may verify whether the data has been loaded correctly by running a sample query on the edges and vertices.